# NameError at /accounts/upload_save/ global name 'ContactForm' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I got an error,NameError at /accounts/upload_save/
global name 'ContactForm' is not defined  .
I am making photo upload system.
Now views.py is like

```
def upload(request, p_id):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST or None)
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', d)

@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('registration/accounts/photo.html')
    else:

        photo_obj.image = files[0]
        photo_obj.image2 = files[1]
        photo_obj.image3 = files[2]

        photo_obj.save()

        photos = Post.objects.all()
        context = {
            'photos': photos,
        }
        return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)
```

Traceback says

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/Downloads/KenshinServer/accounts/views.py" in upload_save
  120.         form = ContactForm(request.POST)

Exception Type: NameError at /accounts/upload_save/
Exception Value: global name 'ContactForm' is not defined]
```

Before,I got an index out of range error in files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]"),I can understand why this error happens empty files cause it .So,I tried to use ContactForm and wrote my code by seeing sample code in django document.However,I got this error and I cannot understand why this error happens.I wanna load photo.html&upload method when files is empty.How can I fix this?

Comment: Indeed it is not defined in that code. Where did you actually define it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did not define it.How should I define it?Is it ok in views.py?Could u write ur intended in answer?

Comment: I really can't understand what you are trying to do here. How can you use things you haven't defined?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you're trying to use some tutorial as a template for your system. Like this [official one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

You should [define a Form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) in your forms.py and import it to use its form_valid() method.